# Trick for removing whitespace between two divs in your IDE?

Tags: html, ide, whitespace, removing-whitespace

There is a problem with HTML and CSS in certain instances where you might have code like this:

```
<div>Element 1</div>
<div>Elemetn 2</div>
```

Sometimes the whitespace generated by the line break causes layout issues.  The obvious fix is as follows:

```
<div>Element 1</div><div>Elemetn 2</div>
```

This isn't ideal in your IDE where you might have multiple elements with lots of content (no line breaks).  At one point I saw a trick to get around this, but I cannot find it.

How can you remove the whitespace without having no line breaks in your file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before submitting I found one option and remembered the one I really liked.

**Option 1:**

```
<div>Element 1</div
><div>Element 2</div>
```

Surprisingly, my IDE didn't mind this at all.  But I still don't love it.

**Option 2 (My preferred option)**

```
   <div>Element 1</div><!--
--><div>Element 2</div>
```

I think this is the best option.  It fixes the issue and still looks fairly nice in the IDE.